# Django translation not working on base html file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation

I don't know what I am missing. I am working with django translation. The traslation works perfectly all apps other than the package folder, i.e app that contains `settings.py`.

My file structure is like this:

```
my-project/
    manage.py
    locale/
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        lacale/
        templates/
            base.html
        urls.py
    profile/
        __init__.py
        locale/
        templates/
            profile/
                profile.html
        views.py
        urls.py
```

Here are the settings file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ....
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ....
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', _('English')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

My `base.html` looks likem **This translation does not work**:

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="author" content="Biplove Lamichhane">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{% trans "Base" %}</h1>
   {% block content %} 
   {% endblock %}
</body>
```

My `profile.html` goes like this, **This translation does work**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}Title{% endblock title %}
        
{% block content %}
    <h2>{% trans "Check" %}</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, I have correctly created `django.po` file and added my translation and compiled messeges to create `django.mo`.

#### Edit

**django.po** for base.html:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-09-21 12:25+0545\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
#: profile/templates/profile/profile.html:9
msgid "Check"
msgstr "Spanish check"
```

**djanog.po** for profile :

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-09-21 21:44+0545\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
#: mysite/settings.py:146
msgid "English"
msgstr ""

#: mysite/settings.py:147
msgid "Spanish"
msgstr ""

#: mysite/templates/base.html:26
msgid "Base"
msgstr "Spanish language for base"
```

Comment: why have you put `{% load i18n %}` twice?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out... that was by mistake while shortening the question... Actually, its just 1.

Comment: show us your `django.po` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you need to add `/mysite/locale` folder to `LOCALE_PATHS`

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'locale'),
)
```

## Update

the key is to make difference between **project** package and **app** package and what default folders (and files) are expected in each package.

in your case, it's obvious that `mysite` folder is the **project package** of your Django application/project which holds (as per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)) **a collection of settings for an instance of Django, including database configuration, Django-specific options and application-specific settings** and **NOT an app** which is recognizable with the the `apps.py` file inside. that's said, Django expects for an **app** like `profile` a bunch default folders like `static`, `templates`, `templatetags`, `migrations` .. and `locale` but for any other non-default location you need to explicitly mention them in `mysite/settings.py`:

for project level or app-independent folders you need to do so :

- global templates `/mysite/templates` (which holds `base.html`)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ..
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ..
    },
]
```

- global static `/mysite/static` (i guess you have already one to hold global assets js, css img ..)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'static')]
```

- and for global locale folder**s**

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),  # underneath project root folder 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'locale'),  # underneath project package 
)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked.. But, can you explain a bit more. Coz, i am just not getting this local paths formula for the main package only.

Comment: Okay ... Now it makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This didn't work for me. LOCALE_PATHS doesn't have any effect, my variable simply appears in original language.

Answer (score 1):

You define a `LOCALE_PATHS` variable in `settings.py` as `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')` that means `my_project/locale/*` and no any others `locale` folders inside apps directories.

So my suggestion is to merge all `.po` files you have into one at `my_projects/locale/` directory. Make sure that path should look like `my_project/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

```py
# django.po
...

#: mysite/settings.py:146
msgid "English"
msgstr ""

#: mysite/settings.py:147
msgid "Spanish"
msgstr ""

#: profile/templates/profile/profile.html:9
msgid "Check"
msgstr "Spanish check"

#: mysite/templates/base.html:26
msgid "Base"
msgstr "Spanish language for base"
```

Comment: **You define a LOCALE_PATHS variable in settings.py as os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale') that means my_project/locale/* and no any others locale folders inside apps directories.**, if then `profile.html` should also not take translation right... Coz, My translation for `profile` are in `profile` app not in root?

Comment: I think merging all the translates in one locale will be so much messy???